# C# Linq - How to merge two lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to I merge a list of strings and a list of classes into a new class list where all elements are one-to-one based on the list of strings but also uses a description from the second list if a matched element exists? Here is my first stab at it:

```
namespace TestListMerge
{
    public class FooClass
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProcessLists 
    {

        List<string> FooCodes = new List<string>()
        {
            "1", "2", "3", "4"
        };

        List<FooClass> FooClasses = new List<FooClass>()
        {
            new FooClass { Code = "5" , Description = "Desc 5" },
            new FooClass { Code = "2" , Description = "Desc 2" },
            new FooClass { Code = "3" , Description = "Desc 3" }
        };

        public IEnumerable<FooClass> MergeLists()
        {
            var returnList = new IEnumerable<FooClass>()

            returnList = FooCodes
                .ForEach(x => x)
                .Select(new FooClass()
                    {
                    Code = x,
                    Description = (FooClasses.Contains(y => y.Code = x) 
                        ? y.Description
                        : null
                    }
                );

            return returnList;
        }
    }
}



var gerenate = new ProcessLists();
var combinedList = gerenate.MergeLists();
```

Comment: In what way does your attempt not work as expected?  At a glance it looks like there's a typo in the use of `Select()`, as you're not passing a callback function but instead just passing an object.  Is that the problem you're encountering?

Comment: It helps to start with the right terminology, and from what I can tell, you want to *join* them, not merge them. There's plenty of information available on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you can turn the `FooClasses` into dictionary and use it (especially if there are a lot of item in `FooClasses`). Also note that this operation is join (more precise - left join), not merge:

```cs
public IEnumerable<FooClass> JoinData()
{
    var dictionary = FooClasses.ToDictionary(f => f.Code, f => f.Description);
    List<FooClass> returnList = FooCodes
        .Select(x => new FooClass()
            {
                Code = x,
                Description = dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(x, "")
            }
        )
        .ToList();

    return returnList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

also,You can use linq (Left join)

If the information matches, they read from the second table, otherwise description is empty

```
public IEnumerable<FooClass> MergeLists()
    {
        return
              from f in FooCodes
              join fc in FooClasses on f equals fc.Code into fcn
              from p in fcn.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new FooClass
              {
                  Code = f,
                  Description = p == null ? "" : p.Description
              };
    }
```